# Display MySQL SELECT results on HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I made so far:
A button that opens a new .html page (in a new browser tab), with some inputs to store data in a MySQL database (by pressing the submit button using `<form>` and a PHP script).

I want to display the content of my MySQL database on my index.html file (e.g. in a `<p>` or a table) by pressing (another) button.

Displaying the content by using a PHP script as when I save something in the database works (like descripted here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp), but I don't want to display the results in a new site, I want to display it in my "index.html".

Is there a proper way for doing this or do I have to make the whole index.html file a PHP file?

Comment: You can use AJAX, for example.

Comment: Usually, you replace `index.html` by `index.php` and do your logic in this PHP file.
If you don't want to have a `*.php` extension in the URL then you could rewrite the URL with an *Apache* rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the .html to .php use ajax to fetch data from db  when you click on your button ,then diplay it on your table

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, what you should keep in mind is that a call to an html or php page is a request made to a web server which delivers the information back to the client, under this paradigm an index.html or index.php It is only executed once, if your SQL query is executed without modifications the first time the page is loaded, it would be enough to make the page design contemplate the space to show the result of said query, if what you want is that the client modify the SQL to show the new result of said query in your page index.html or index.php you should reload the page with the new query or else use ajax to only reload a part of the page and make ajax perform the loading the data with the new query.

In any case index.html can contain php or php code it can also contain html

index.php

```php
echo "<html>"; 
echo "</html>";
```

index.html

```html
<html>
<?php
echo "some php code"; 
?>
</html>
```